# R hold list of variables to supply a function

Tags: r, function, variables

For a situation of many R processes, using a particular function currently hard coded as follows:

```
processa <- c("var1","var2","var3","var4")
processb <- c("var1","var5","var7")
processc <- c("var8")
```

The need is to change it to where the "varX" list is held as value, something like this:

```
processa <- c(Value)
processb <- c(Value)
processc <- c(Value)
```

The plan is to import the 'Value' from an Excel file (so configs for the processes can be changed without updating multiple codes), what I end up getting is the following which doesn't work.

```
"\"var1\", \"var2\", \"var3\", \"var4\""
```

Comment: What you are describing is certainly possible in a number of different ways, but the method depends on how you are reading the data in from Excel, and in what way it is stored in Excel. Is the string `"var1", "var2", "var3", "var4"` all stored in a single cell, or are they in multiple cells? How are you importing from Excel? Are you copy-pasting or using a package? How much leeway do you have in changing the Excel? These questions all affect the method you would use, and without knowing these things, folks here are likely to find your question difficult to answer.

Comment: Thank you @AllanCameron yes, I agree, I was trying not to overload the question and hoping to gauge what the reaction was first, and I do understand what I am trying to do may not be the best approach to the situation, so any other ideas are welcomed, but currently we use the same Excel config file for Python processes and it works there in the format we currently have.  I need to split this comment up ...

Comment: ......For R I have tried holding the variables in one cell in Excel as `"var1", "var2", "var3", "var4"`  **or**  `var1, var2, var3, var4` **or** `var1 var2 var3 var4` I can't seem to get the same as hardcoding a character string. For example if I hard code `xyz<-  c( "var1", "var2", "var3", "var4")`, then use `processa <- xyz` the function will run, however I can't seem to manipulate the imported values to replicate that.

Comment: Importing into RStudio using read.xlsx2, the using this to filter to the cell - `Targets<-filter(importedfile,rowname="RowNeeded")$ColNeeded`

Comment: In that case @Evan, the solution would be to parse the string. You could do this for example with `strsplit(gsub("\\"", "", Targets), ", ")[[1]]` which should give you a vector in R equivalent to the result of typing `c("var1,", "var2", "var3", "var4")` into the console.

Comment: In the Excel cell it is

`"var1","var2","var3","var4"`

`Targets<-filter(importedfile,rowname="RowNeeded")$ColNeeded
Targets`
 
looks like this


`"\"var1\",\"var2\",\"var3\",\"var4\""`

`strsplit(gsub("\\"", "", Targets), ", ")[[1]]`

gives the following error

`Error: unexpected string constant in "strsplit(gsub("\\"", ""`

Comment: Sorry Evan, there was an extra backslash in there. Try `strsplit(gsub("\"", "", Targets), ", ")[[1]]`

Comment: Thankyou again @AllanCameron that gets me to

`"var1,var2,var3,var4"`

What I am hoping for is

`"var1", "var2", "var3", "var4"`

Comment: that's not the output I get with the given input - please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The comments were becoming a bit of an epic here, so I thought I would post this as a reproducible example of how to get a vector from the given input:

```r
excel_output <- "\"var1\", \"var2\", \"var3\", \"var4\""
excel_output
#> [1] "\"var1\", \"var2\", \"var3\", \"var4\""
```

So now we do:

```
strsplit(gsub("\"", "", excel_output), ", ")[[1]]
#> [1] "var1" "var2" "var3" "var4"
```

Comment: thankyou again, your worked example is certainly doing as expected, unfortunately that doesn't work with the actual data I am using. I think I have taken up enough of your time for now, I need to go back and re-think this process perhaps?

Comment: @Evan if you just make a reproducible example and show where you're stuck, I'm happy to help

Comment: Cheers @AllanCameron, will take a look at that, but give you a break for the day:-) I thought maybe holding it in a tab delimited file as opposed to Excel it would work, but I get the same thing. I will pull together all the bits to help reproduce it all soon.

Comment: I finally got this to work by changing how the data is held in Excel. Holding the variables in separate rows so I can import them and make them a list `Targets<-filter(importedfile, rowname=='RowNeeded')$ColNeeded
xyz<-as.list(Target)`